# Unable to parse a nested JSON in an AJAX response

Tags: jquery, json

I have written a code in jQuery/AJAX to query Elasticsearch and return a list of documents based on the search criteria. I am able to get the documents from Elasticsearch. I am trying to parse the documents and display them in a webpage. Here is the response from the Elasticsearch index.

```
   {
  "took": 12,
  "timed_out": false,
  "_shards": {
    "total": 1,
    "successful": 1,
    "skipped": 0,
    "failed": 0
  },
  "hits": {
    "total": {
      "value": 4,
      "relation": "eq"
    },
    "max_score": 1.617034,
    "hits": [
      {
        "_index": "test",
        "_type": "_doc",
        "_id": "uhp0sW0BO2MOKYEQa-CB",
        "_score": 1.617034,
        "_source": {
          "MsgTime": "2019-10-09T16:57:39.829Z",
          "OrganizationID": "nasa",
          "UserID": "USER1",
          "TravelID": "1234",
          "MachineID": "9099",
          "Stage": "ingested"
        }
      },
      {
        "_index": "test",
        "_type": "_doc",
        "_id": "sxpnsW0BO2MOKYEQ9eAo",
        "_score": 1.617034,
        "_source": {
          "MsgTime": "2019-10-09T16:44:03.102Z",
          "OrganizationID": "nasa",
          "UserID": "USER1",
          "TravelID": "201710283fc113afa731459285b55d94bb8ddf02",
          "MachineID": "9099",
          "Stage": "processed"
        }
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

The output I am trying to achieve on a webpage is as follows for each "_source" element under "hits". The values will differ wherever applicable.

```
          "MsgTime": "2019-10-09T16:57:39.829Z",
          "OrganizationID": "nasa",
          "UserID": "USER1",
          "TravelID": "1234",
          "MachineID": "9099",
          "Stage": "ingested"
```

I tried to parse the output as an AJAX response in jQuery using the following code (just the parsing piece)

```
     $(document).ready(function() {
            $("#search").click(function() {
                var textboxvalue = $("#trip_id").val();                            
                    $.ajax({
                        url: myURL,
                        type: "GET",
                        dataType: 'json',
                        data: query = {
                                q: "TravelID: " +textboxvalue,
                                pretty:'true',
                                size:100
                        },
                        success: function( result ) { 

                            $.each( result, function( key, value ) {
                                $.each(value,function(hits,v){
                                    $.each(v,function(i,hits){
                                        $.each(hits,function(_source,v){
                                            console.log(_source,v);
                                        });
                                    });
                                });
                            });
```

In the parsing piece, I am unable to get the final output. I am unsure if my last $.each loop is correct.

I can provide more information if needed. I have excluded the HTML here.

Thanks in advance,
Nick

Answer (score 1):

I extracted your parsing statement. It can essentially be reduced to the following:

```js
obj =
{ "took": 12, "timed_out": false, "_shards": { "total": 1, "successful": 1, "skipped": 0, "failed": 0 }, "hits": { "total": { "value": 4, "relation": "eq" }, "max_score": 1.617034, "hits": [ { "_index": "test", "_type": "_doc", "_id": "uhp0sW0BO2MOKYEQa-CB", "_score": 1.617034, "_source": { "MsgTime": "2019-10-09T16:57:39.829Z", "OrganizationID": "nasa", "UserID": "USER1", "TravelID": "1234", "MachineID": "9099", "Stage": "ingested" } }, { "_index": "test", "_type": "_doc", "_id": "sxpnsW0BO2MOKYEQ9eAo", "_score": 1.617034, "_source": { "MsgTime": "2019-10-09T16:44:03.102Z", "OrganizationID": "nasa", "UserID": "USER1", "TravelID": "201710283fc113afa731459285b55d94bb8ddf02", "MachineID": "9099", "Stage": "processed" } } ] } }

console.log(obj.hits.hits.map(v=>v._source))
```

In your JavaScript object you have an object `hits` that you can directly address and in that you have an array `hits` that you can also address directly. To get the contents of the contained object with the `_source` attribute you need to use a looping technique like the `.map()` shown above.

Comment: Thanks for the response. Let me try it out...Appreciate your quick help.

Comment: Worked like a charm. Is the map() function same as map reduce ?

Comment: `.map()` returns an array, while `.reduce((acc,curr)=>{...; return acc}, acc_initobj)` will return the object `acc_initobj` after it has been sent through all of the callback function calls as`acc`.